# Change Master Page Content without loading page multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, master-pages

I have Master and Content Page.The Layout is like Header and Footer are in Master page and rest contents are in content/child page.

Now I want to change the header and footer of master page dynamically.To do this,I have coded Page_load event of master page.

But Actual problem comes that when Master page's header and footer changes,the page loads multiple times..

Is there any way to solve this problem..
I want to change header and footer of master page for specific time without refreshing content page.

I have seen many post, but i did not find any accurate answer..

My code is :
this is the page_load event of master page ..

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DIVHeader.InnerHtml = obj.getHeaderHTMLFinal();
            DIVFooter.InnerHtml = obj.getFooterHTMLFinal();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to change the footer on the Master Page?

You could wrap the header and footer in ContentPlaceholder controls and adjust them in client pages directly.

You can also interact with the Master Page in client pages in code behind via the [Page.Master](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx) property.

Comment: @Frazell..I did this.i set the header and footer of master in load event of content page but due to this page loads three times..

Comment: @ravidev how is the page loading three times exactly?

Comment: i dont know why page loads three times.but when i changes the content of header and footer through Page_load event of Master Page Or Content Page,It loads it three times..

Comment: @ravidev Is there anything in the HTML source that triggers the multiple loads? The browser can't just refresh the page without being instructed to do so first (HTTP is state less).

Comment: @frazell..i have div in my header and footer in which i m setting html data of master page.

Comment: @ravidev How is that Div setting the content? This seems like the root of your issue. You might need to clarify your question with what is failing in the interaction between the JavaScript and the server.

Comment: @frazell..currently i am not using javscript.i set div of header and footer using code behind.in Load event of master page.this causes the pages to load three times..

Comment: @ravidev Can you edit your question to include some of the code (HTML and code behind)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an updatepanel. You can update the content of the panel without reload the whole page.

If in your header or footer you do not have controls that triggers an update then you can manual trigger the update of the panel from code behind using conditional update.

hope that helped.